# как добавить в словарь новый ключ

Tags: python, python-3.x

Попробовала добавить вот таким образом, но не получилось т.к выдает ошибку

```
ab = {
    'Алина : +79069594861',
    'Вика : +79989163931',
    'Максим : +79278939487',
    'Никита : +79629371475',
 }
print('Вы вошли в контакты\nДоступные вам команды:\nдобавить')
inp = input()

if inp.lower() == "добавить":
    print('Введите имя нового контакта:')
    contact = input()
    print('Введите номер нового контакта:')
    phone = input()
ab[contact] = phone
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас сейчас Ваш словарь не содержит значений `ключ-значение`, а просто одно значение.
Чтобы добавить ключи - экранируйте данные в словаре отдельно. 
Пример:

```py
ab = {
    'Алина' : '+79069594861',
    'Вика' : '+79989163931',
    'Максим' : '+79278939487',
    'Никита' : '+79629371475'
 }
print('Вы вошли в контакты\nДоступные вам команды:\nдобавить')
inp = input()

if inp.lower() == "добавить":
    print('Введите имя нового контакта:')
    contact = input()
    print('Введите номер нового контакта:')
    phone = input()
    ab[contact] = phone
print(ab)
```

Comment: В вопросе даже не словарь, а множество